# Runtime Error , Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

```
#include <cmath> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

/* Your algorithms have become so good at predicting the market that you now know what the share price of Wooden Orange Toothpicks Inc. (WOT) will be for the next N days.
```

Each day, you can either buy one share of WOT, sell any number of shares of WOT that you own, or not make any transaction at all. What is the maximum profit you can obtain with an optimum trading strategy? */

```
struct data{
    int index;
    long value;
};

bool comp(const data &a,const data &b)
    {
        return a.value > b.value;
}

int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int t;
    long n;
    int i,j;

    cin>>t;
    while(t)
        {
        t=t-1;
        cin>>n;
        long arr[n];
        long buy=0,sell=0;
        long buy_count=0;
        vector<data> copy;
        long max = 0;
        int indix=0;
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            cin>>arr[i];
            //copy[i] = arr[i];
            data s;
            s.index = i;
            s.value = arr[i];
            copy.push_back(s);
           }
        //sort to get the maximum elements and their positions at the top
        sort(copy.begin(),copy.end(),comp);
        //cout<<copy[0].value;
        max = copy[0].value;
        indix = copy[0].index;
        int c=0;

        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            if(i<indix)
                {
                //buy a share
                buy+=arr[i];
                buy_count+=1;
            }
            else if(i==indix && i!=0)
                {

                //time to sell
                sell+= buy_count*(arr[i]);
                cout<<"in sell : sell :"<<sell<<endl;
                c++;
                cout<<"hello";// not printing , giving runtime error over here
                buy_count = 0;
                while(i>copy[c].index)
                    {
                    c++;
                }
                cout<<"hello";
                max = copy[c].value;
                indix = copy[c].index;                
            }
        }

        cout<<(sell-buy)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a homework helping site.  Please ask a specific question about a problem you're having with this code rather than asking us to solve a question for you.

Comment: Find out how to create array with dynamic size or how to use `std::vector`. Preferably both.

Comment: What platform are you using? `long arr[n];` is not valid C++ code.

Comment: `cin>>n; long arr[n];` is valid in C and as some compiler extensions for C++. Why even use a raw array when you are already using `std::vector`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but segmentation fault occurring due to this code section:

```
while(i>copy[c].index)
{
    c++;
}
cout<<"hello";
max = copy[c].value;
indix = copy[c].index;
```

Here you are accessing `vector` without checking it's `size`, you need to implement some `size check` here. Something like this.

```
while(c < copy.size()-1 && i>copy[c].index) //! Here size()-1 because later you are using c as a index so it should always be less than size.
{
    c++;
}
cout<<"hello";
max = copy[c].value;
indix = copy[c].index;
```